Default Editor - columns not printing
I am using the default Wordpress editor to create a layout with 2 columns. These display as columns on screen as expected.
However when I got to print, the columns appear vertically, effectively as rows not columns. How can I make these print as columns?
Searching the css I can't find any @media tags that should be causing the layout to vary for print.
Tested in both Chrome and Edge, so I don't think this is browser related.
Minimal test case visible at www.coastalcocoa.co.uk/colprinttest. Go to print preview to see "test1" above "test2".

The columns appear vertically because when printing, the viewport is considered quite narrow. For the column blocks to appear horizontally next to each other, they have this in the CSS for the core/columns block:
@media (min-width:782px) {
  .wp-block-columns {
    flex-wrap:nowrap!important
  }
}

This media query does not pass when printing, thus the columns appear vertically. You may wish to add your own CSS to apply this when printing, for example:
@media print {
  .wp-block-columns {
    flex-wrap:nowrap!important
  }
}

You may also wish to qualify this with an extra class to ensure the above would not affect any other columns blocks:
<!-- wp:columns {"className":"foo",…} -->
<div class="wp-block-columns foo">

@media print {
  .wp-block-columns.foo {
    flex-wrap:nowrap!important
  }
}

